# While deploying in serverless Framework im geeting this issue? Deprecation Warning?

Tags: deployment

Deprecation warning: CLI options definitions were upgraded with "type" property (which could be one of "string", "boolean", "multiple"). Below listed plugins do not predefine type for introduced options: - ServerlessPlugin for "out" - ServerlessOffline for "apiKey", "corsAllowHeaders", "corsAllowOrigin", "corsDisallowCredentials", "corsExposedHeaders", "disableCookieValidation", "enforceSecureCookies", "hideStackTraces", "host", "httpPort", "httpsProtocol", "lambdaPort", "noPrependStageInUrl", "noAuth", "ignoreJWTSignature", "noTimeout", "prefix", "printOutput", "resourceRoutes", "useChildProcesses", "useWorkerThreads", "websocketPort", "webSocketHardTimeout", "webSocketIdleTimeout", "useDocker", "layersDir", "dockerReadOnly", "functionCleanupIdleTimeSeconds", "allowCache", "dockerHost", "dockerHostServicePath", "dockerNetwork" - WarmUp for "warmers" Please report this issue in plugin issue tracker.

Comment: Please reformat your question

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the "serverless-offline" module to "^8.5.0" fixed my problem

```
// package.json
"devDependencies": {
    "serverless-offline": "^8.5.0"
  },
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.